# Preventing the entry of formulas in cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I'm using MS Excel 2007. I would like to restrict the data entry of some cells in a worksheet to certain numeric values and also forbid the entry of formulas in those cells.

As an example, given this data

```
   |  A |  B |  C
---+----+----+-----
 1 |  4 | 26 |
 2 |    |    |
```

I would like to only allow literal numeric values greater than 100 to be entered in `C1`.

I tried using `Data`→`Data Validation`→[`Allow`=`Decimal`, `Data`=`Greater than`, `Minimum`=`100`] but this also allows certain formulas to be inputted. If you try entering `=A1*B1` in cell `C1`, because it evaluates to more than 100, the data validation allows the formula.

How do I enforce this extra no-formula restriction?

Comment: Write proper Worksheet_Change. Check the range changed, and if it contains restricted cells, undo changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without using any VBA. All that is required is a custom data validation and changing the number format of the cell:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing the Data Validation Formula]

Enter the following as the custom data validation formula  for `C1`:

```dart
=VALUE(C1)>100
```

Then change the number format of the cell to `Text`:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing the Number Format]

All attempts to enter a formula will now trigger a data validation error.

**Caveats:**

You just need to be careful when using the entered values. Calculations should work fine, but comparisons with actual numbers won't work correctly. It is simplest to always wrap the value with a `VALUE()` function whenever you need to use it.